# Cannot read parameter name (!not value) from Excel

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

The idea is to create a keyword framework with dynamic properties, as much as possible. Keywords to read from Excel:

```
Keyword=Trim(TS_Sheet.cells(j,"D"))
Arg1=Trim(TS_Sheet.cells(j,"E"))
Arg2=Trim(TS_Sheet.cells(j,"F"))
Arg3=Trim(TS_Sheet.cells(j,"G"))
Arg4=Trim(TS_Sheet.cells(j,"H"))
'Execute the corresponding test Steps(Or Keywords)
Call_Function Keyword, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4
```

Call_Function should execute steps:

```
Function Call_Function (Keyword, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4)
On Error Resume Next
Print "Keyword for execution is:- " & Keyword
Dim subS1 : Set subS1 = GetRef(cstr(Keyword))(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4)
    If Err.Num<>0 Then
        Msgbox "Error: "&Err.Num, "OK", "Runtime Error "&Err.Num
        reporter.ReportNote "Error occured: "&Err.Num&" keyword: "&keyword&" TCID: "&TCID&" TSID: "&TSID
    End If
Mybrowser.Sync
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
Set subS1 = Nothing
End Function
```

I need to wait for a property to be reached using WaitProperty, Chekproperty or any other methot, like

```
MyBrowser.WebButton("html id:=.*"&Arg2).WaitProperty ("disabled", Arg4, 1)
```

BUT I need to pass the parameter to wait from Excel to make it more dynamic, like

```
MyBrowser.ChildObject("micclass:=.*"&Arg1, "html id:=.*"&Arg2).WaitProperty (Arg3, Arg4, 1)
```

So far, it did not work. QTP just skips that part of code.
I tried something like following:

```
Function Wait_Property (Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4)
    Process=".."
    Do
    For Iterator = 1 To 100 Step 0.5 '///this can be any number just to make sure loop executes long enough to property to be reached
    If MyBrowser.ChildObject("micclass:=.*"&Arg1, "html id:=.*"&Arg2).WaitProperty (Arg3, Arg4, 0.1) Then
        Print "Reached."
        Exit Do
    Else
        Print "Wait. Processing.."&Process
        Wait 0.5
    End If
    Process = Process+".."
    Next
    Loop While False
End Function
```

Also I tried `...If MyBrowser.ChildObject("micclass:=.*"&Arg1, "html id:=.*"&Arg2, Arg3=Arg4).Exist Then...` but QTP still skips that.

What's wrong? Is there any other way to do that?

**UPD 1:**
The following is working now:

```
PropWait = cstr(Browser("micclass:=Browser","CreationTime:=0","name:=.*").page("micclass:=Page","CreationTime:=0","Title:=.*").WebButton("html id:=.*"&Arg2).GetROProperty(Arg3))
Do Until cstr(PropWait) = cstr(Arg4)
If PropWait = Arg4 Then
    Exit Do
    ElseIf PropWait = "" Then 
print "PropWait Empty"
    Exit Do
    Else
End If
Wait 2
Print PropWait&" : Wait. Processing.."&Process
Process = Process+".."
PropWait = cstr(Browser("micclass:=Browser","CreationTime:=0","name:=.*").page("micclass:=Page","CreationTime:=0","Title:=.*").WebButton("html id:=.*"&Arg2).GetROProperty(Arg3))
Loop
```

But I need micclass to be dynamic, too.

**UPD 2:**
Added description.create to previous update:

```
Dim WaitObj : Set WaitObj = Description.Create
WaitObj("micclass").Value = Arg1
WaitObj("html id").Value = Arg2

PropWait = Browser("micclass:=Browser","name:=.*").page("micclass:=Page","Title:=.*").ChildObjects(WaitObj).GetROProperty(Arg3)
```

But QTP skips it and everything following this peace.

**UPD 3**:

As advised in comments, tried to comment `On Error Resume Next` in `Call_Function`, but now after first step (which is to open browser) it returns error:

> "Object required: 'GetRef(...)(...)"

**UPD 4:**
Tried to put `On Error Resume Next` in Wait_Property Function: (`On Error Resume Next` in `Call_Function` uncommented)

```
Function Wait_Property (Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4)
On Error Resume Next
...
```

Now, not sure if it recognizes the object, but it prints next (while the property in Arg3 has a value:

> PropWait =
>
> PropWait Empty

Comment: QTP only skips if you have `On Error Resume Next`. Comment it and see which error you are getting.

Comment: Thnx @ManishCristian, I commented that.
Function is called by another function:
`Function Call_Function (Keyword, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4)
'On Error Resume Next
Print "Keyword for execution is:- " & Keyword
Dim subS1 : Set subS1 = GetRef(cstr(Keyword))(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4)
 If Err.Num<>0 Then
  Msgbox "Error: "&Err.Num, "OK", "Runtime Error "&Err.Num
  reporter.ReportNote "Error occured: "&Err.Num&" keyword: "&keyword&" TCID: "&TCID&" TSID: "&TSID
 End If
Mybrowser.Sync
'Err.Clear
End Function`

Comment: The first Keyword is to open browser - which works. But second keyword returns error: "Object required: 'GetRef(...)(...)"
With "On Error..." all keywords run and execute with no problem (except the micclass part of the function in the question)

Comment: The `Wait_Property` function does not have `On Error Resume Next`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the next is working:

```
Function Wait_Property (Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4)
print "Test Function Call"

Dim WObj : Set WObj = Description.Create()
WObj("micclass").Value = Arg1
WObj("html id").Value = Arg2

Dim ObjColl : Set ObjColl = MyBrowser.ChildObjects(WObj)
For t = 0 To ObjColl.Count-1
'print "count:="&ObjColl.Count
  WaitPro = cstr(ObjColl(t).GetROProperty(Arg3))
  Do Until WaitPro = Arg4
    print "Wait. Progress..."&Progress
    wait 2
    Progress = Progress+".."
    Set ObjColl = MyBrowser.ChildObjects(WObj)
    WaitPro = cstr(ObjColl(t).GetROProperty(Arg3))
  Loop
  print "Function Executed"
Next

Set WObj = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Should I "Accept" my own answer? ))